# Is Ruby on Rails good for large scale projects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working on a presentation about RoR. It's looking good except I cannot really find anything for a "Problems" section. There seems to be none. :)

Particularly I am interested in:

1. What issues are there with maintainability/management when multiple developers are involved in large-scale RoR project?
2. What specific considerations are there for developers on such large-scale projects using dynamically typed languages versus statically typed languages?
3. Why might RoR not be suitable for large-scale projects?

I could not find anything on this googling the Internet. I would like to hear your thoughts about these points?

Thank you,
Arkadiy

Comment: i'm quite sure code quality and framework applicability depends more on team management and other tools than on language and framework. can't quote anything from top of my head at the moment

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14823/is-ruby-on-rails-ready-for-the-enterprise and http://www.infoq.com/articles/changing-the-present-case-stud

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm certain you can find a lot of this on the 'net, but I'm happy to oblige.

1. Maintainability: Ruby and Rails are all about creating more maintainable code at the expense of a little performance. That's why Ruby is a dynamic language in the first place. As far as developers/teams are concerned, Rails is great for creating and maintaining code that is easy to understand and maintain.
2. Dynamic vs Static: From the perspective of a development team, static languages have a the unique advantage of being very explicit. There isn't magic to confuse new developers, and there should be little work in terms of chasing down ghosts (in theory, anyways). That advantage is quickly outweighed by the ability of a dynamic language to really take advantage of OOP and get started developing quickly.
3. Suitability: I can't think of any good reasons. It's test-driven, proven, and extremely well designed. It was made to do the job, so it doesn't surprise me that this is the case. :)

Comment: There are two sides of Rails coin. On one side, you have powerful tools at your disposal, allowing you to develop fast in a proper way. On the other side, there are so called best practices by mainstream rails community, which in reality are a recipe for disaster, like fat models etc. In the end, it all comes to your own culture and methods that will result in a maintainable project.

Comment: You mention maintainability. And for years Rails community is going for 'skinny controllers, fat models', a half-right mantra. There are more examples like that. I'm not bashing anything, just mentioning the common pitfalls that I encountered on my journey with Rails. There are lots of 'enterprise' level apps out there written with Rails, and it all comes to developers to build maintainable code in the end.

Answer (score 2):

Most RoR developer team works on **MAC** in my experience.
Using **git** or **svn** for version control. Most use **TextMate** or **Komodo**.
Special with **Komodo Pro** you can use it well in teams.
A good svn client there is **Versions**

I didn't worked in bigger teams then 5 developers, that isn't large scale I think :) But the framework itself is much easier to handle like most other I have seen. Mostly used in Scrum-Teams but if yo have a good organisation I don't see any disadvantage using RoR in large teams.

The code documentation tools are handy, splitting the models, controllers and views up in different sections for team members shouldn't be a big deal and setting up test servers with nightly builts is very easy.

We use RoR in linux and windows environments and have very good productive experience made with it. Technical it is as scaleable as other large frameworks, with `sql_sessions` and `mem_cache` you can setup easy a server farm to run it for thousands or millions of users.

So imho: It is capable for any size of team.

Answer (score 1):

For scalability, if twitter can doit so i think you can do it too.

And Maintainability, like in any other programming language, you need use some kind of versions control, svn or git.

Comment: Twitter's backend is no longer on Rails. They are running on Scala. That's how they can do it.

Comment: Twitter use Scala and RoR ;) http://www.artima.com/scalazine/articles/twitter_on_scala.html